# Taking data from within webconfig

Tags: javascript, web-config

Can I show the fttproot and httpserver values ​​in webconfig in the script? If so, how can I show it? Could you help?

```html
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="datapath" value="C:\Mikromax" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ftpserver"  value="212.58.14.178" />
    <add key="ftpuser"  value="admin" />
    <add key="ftproot"  value="Download" />
    <add key="ftppass"  value="mmx-ftp" />
  
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject this values into aspx as follows:

```
<script>
    var ftpRoot = '<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftproot"]%>';
    var ftpServer = '<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpserver"]%>';
    var apiUrl = '<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["datapath"]%>';
</script>
```

Comment: As a string. The values ​​did not come

Comment: It did not happen again

Comment: Can you please provide more details? I've tried this within a new web project few mins ago and it worked well for me.

Comment: Of course. Devexment project. Web service API project is separate. Devextreme web application is located in different projects. I need to be able to get the value of ftproot and ftpserver in the script. Such..